# how to check if notebook is triggered automatically (scheduled job) or manually?

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks

Wanted to know if there is a way to implement a logic in notebook to check if notebook is manually triggered or automatically run(scheduled job)?

The requirement is, when job is runs automatically, I have to take the current date as input Parmeter or when job is manually triggered then, I need to pick user provided date. Is there any help would be appreciated! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by manually is triggered interactively, then you can check if the current run ID is defined or not - you can get it from the notebook context.  Something like this:

```py
dbutils.widgets.text("date", "", "Enter date")
# another cell
from datatime import date
is_job = dbutils.notebook.entry_point.getDbutils().notebook().getContext().currentRunId().isDefined()
if is_job:
  d = date.today()
else:
  d = date.fromisoformat(dbutils.widgets.get("date"))
...
```