# How to check in calling notebook if databricks job are launched manually or by scheduler?

Tags: databricks, spark-notebook

How to check in calling notebook if databricks job are launched manually or by scheduler? any help would be really appreciated.

I need this because I have to pass the Parameters or arguments based on the launcher. in my case if the databricks job is manually launched then, I need to take the user provided input or if it is launched through the scheduler then, I need to generate separate parameters.

Comment: it's already asked & answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76309610/how-to-check-if-notebook-is-triggered-automatically-scheduled-job-or-manually/76312369#76312369